# How do I line up the positions of a div and a pre?

Tags: css, css-position

Suppose I have a `pre` and a `div`:

```
<pre>Hello</pre>
<div>Hello</div>
```

And I give them positioning and dimensioning with `position: absolute` and friends:

```
pre {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
    left: 5%;
    right: 50%;
    bottom: 5%;
}
div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
    left: 50%;
    right: 5%;
    bottom: 5%;
}
```

Then the `pre` starts lower vertically and ends higher vertically. You can see what I mean on this [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6hp34/2/).

How can I make the `pre` and the `div` line up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `margin:0` to your `pre`. ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6hp34/6/))

Answer (score 1):

Some elements have default attribute values. In this case, `pre` has a default top and bottom margin of 13px which need to be overridden in order to make it display like you want.

See http://jsfiddle.net/K3WcC/

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @canon's answer you can reset global defaults:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```